# Custom Calendar like Google Flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar

I am trying to achieve this type of calendar with flutter. Its similar to that of google calendar which highlights the week day while closed and toggles to show the full month when tapped. Is there any library around to achieve this?

[image: sample image]

Comment: try with both https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar and  https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar

Comment: you have any code example for this?

Comment: It's present on their github pages respectively - [flutter_calendar](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples) and [table_calendar](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar)